# Extracting custom tags from text file

Tags: c#, string, tagging

I am creating my own file tagging system for an application and have not found any relevant information on the subject.

My application appends tags to the end of a specified file, like so:

If the user wants to mark a particular file as private (for example), the following text will be appended to the end of the specified file:

$/private*

---

Now, I'm trying to figure out how I would extract those tags, and separate them when the file is loaded into my application:

For example, if the file has 3 tags, named "Private", "bad", "jokes". Then I want my application to get those tags and display them like so:

This file is marked as private, and contains bad jokes.

OR - Another way to show them would be:

This file has the following tags:
Private
Bad
Jokes

---

Does anybody know how I would go about doing this? I'm thinking maybe using strings as I don't like Regex. It gives me headaches.

Comment: Do you mean as in read the file to a string buffer then doing if (buffer.contains(tag) == true)?

Comment: Is it plain text files?

If they are all at the end of the file, could you read all lines, loop from the back and extract tags when line starts with $/ and ends in *?

Comment: Thank you Mikael, I was thinking of that, however I do not know how to loop from the back. Also, there could be more than one tag on a single line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can put markers for marking beginning of tags and separate tags from each other:

```
main text of the file.......................
+++$$$+++private|bad|jokes+++$$$+++
```

then you can load the text of file and extract the tags based on the sentinels setup by you.

Comment: Thanks TheVilliageIdiot! This is excellent!! I completely understand your answer and am going to get on it right away, once I have it working, I'll post the code here for others to see.

Comment: Sure do post it @baeltazor that's why SO rocks!